# Joi validation in case of alternatives

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation, joi

There is an object which has three keys

```
const abc = {
  customerId: '777',
  firstName: 'pqr'',
  lastName: 'xyz',
};
```

The condition is that if customer id is present then firstname and lastname could be ignored. Otherwise, they should be strings of max length 20.

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  customerId: Joi.string(),
  firstName: Joi.alternatives().when('customerId', {
    is: null,
    then: Joi.string(),
  }),
  lastName: Joi.alternatives().when('customerId', {
    is: null,
    then: Joi.string(),
  })
})
Joi.validate(abc, schema);
```

Here I get this error

> error:     { ValidationError: "firstName" is not allowed
>       at Object.exports.process (/home/runner/node_modules/joi/lib/errors.js:

So, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.or` instead of `when`.

Here's a running example: https://repl.it/@amasad/joi

Schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  customerId: Joi.string(),
  firstName: Joi.string().max(20),
  lastName: Joi.string().max(20),
}).or('customerId', 'lastName')
  .or('customerId', 'firstName');
```

Comment: according to your answer, it will either be customer id and lastname or customerid and firstname. But what if the case when customerid is not there then both firstname and lastname should be present.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your schema looks for `firstname` while your object has `firstName` instead. Try without the capital `N`.

```
const abc = {
   customerId: '777',
   firstname: 'pqr',
   lastname: 'xyz'
};
```

Comment: There should be a different error after this correction. Can you check on that? @Aayushi